# Mathematical Induction: How do I prove any number >= 25 follows the equation 5a + 7b?

Tags: prime-numbers, induction

The statement goes like this:

"Prove that for integer n >= 25, there are non-negative integers a and b such that 5a + 7b = n."

The base step, 25, is easy.

The induction step is harder to prove even though I know it probably has something to do with the prime number, but I can't see the connection.

Comment: This is a special case of the [Frobenius Coin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) for two coins of values $5$ and $7$.

Comment: I would not be surprised if you find out that this (or a very similar) question has been asked before. I was able to find, for example, [Show that for any natural number $n>24$ there exist natural numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $ n=5p+7q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1511998) and [What would be the induction hypothesis in my proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1971640)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
25= 5 \times 5 + 7 \times 0 \\
26= 5 \times 1 + 7 \times 3 \\
27= 5 \times 4 + 7 \times 1 \\
28= 5 \times 0 + 7 \times 4 \\
29= 5 \times 3 + 7 \times 2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now add whatever multiple of $5$ to whichever one of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you can show that the numbers 26, 27, 28, 29 are doable, then you're done, because any number greater than 25 will be one of those numbers plus some multiple of 5. Can you use this in your inductive step?

Comment: For a more formal proof, you would use "strong induction": for 25 through 29 you establish those directly.  For the other cases, apply the inductive hypothesis on $n-5$ which is valid since $n-5 < n$ and $n-5 \ge 25$, then complete the proof along the lines of what's being suggested.

Answer (score 0):

do the following find the breakdown for n=25 through 29 then just add one to b and you get the next five. etc. so if you can prove those cases you can prove it for all cases above 25.